# time measurements between CBPeripheralManager advertisment

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I know from the Central side you can find the time between a peripheral's advertisements, but I would like to know if you could do this on the peripheral side.

For instance, lets say I have an algorithm that uses time as an input.  Now lets look at two consecutive advertisements. the first advertisement will conveniently be from 0-20 ms and the second advertisement will be from 21-40 ms.  My algorithms results are:

result 1 = algorithm output for 0-20 ms or the time interval between the start advertising call and the actual time the first advertisement is sent.

result 2 = algorithm output for 21-40 ms or the time interval between the first advertisement and the second advertisement.

I know there is going to be some lagging due to algorithm processing time and advertisement packet building time, but I would like to know if its possible to record the algorithms output as a string from 0-19 or almost 20 ms until an advertisement is ready to be sent out at 20 ms with that string.  Then after that, the second advertisment will pick up the algorithms output where the first advertisement left off such as at 20 or 21 ms until its time for that second advertisement to be sent out at 40 ms. I cannot find this in apples documentation.  The thing is I know I will not be able to predict when the advertisement will be sent out.  I just want to basically say:

-When advertisement 1 is sent out at t1

{

send out data gathered from 0 - t1;

}

-When advertisement 2 is sent out at t2

{

send out data gathered from t1 - t2;

}

Again I know the time you end the interval cannot be the exact same time you send out the advertisement.  I just want something very close to it.  Also I know i could just do the algorithm on the central side using the time elapsed between advertisements received but i actually want to use this with the peripherals sensor readings as well such as total magnetometer readings between advertisement intervals.

Thanks and sorry for the long explanation.

Comment: Why do you care about advertisement interval? Seems like you want to communicate. Sending the data you mention is not practical in advertisement. In this case use a connection to send the data. Just send indications and sample with the rate dictated by the central. On an external device you can synchronize the data collection and sending but on iOS you won't have any precise means to dot that.

Comment: Im storing the string in the UUID and I dont want to connect

Comment: And is it possible to change the advertised services so fast? This is not a planned use case so I suspect the stack will get corrupted pretty fast. It happens even with planned use cases. I suggest you run some tests before going too deep in this way. I'm really interested in your findings. But it will surely not be possible to change every 20ms. Also, keep in mind that in backgrounded mode the services are removed from the advertisement packages.

Comment: Maybe I will connect it then.  I knew back when i started this project I saw a problem with connecting in the background and I decided it would be quicker to just advertise.  I have forgot that reason and now I still look for it.  Maybe I will connect.  Do you know of any drawbacks of connecting with multiple devices in the background?

Comment: 1. your app can be killed (restoration may help) 2. the connection will be stable at most up to about 5-6 peers (8 is said to be the max but it will surely crash...) You should minimize the number of simultaneous connections. Maybe some day we'll have multicast groups for BLE. :)